# Ionic4 type angular always loads Homepage

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, ionic4, angular7-router

My Ionic4 App always loads the homepage. I tried to initialize it as loadChildren, component and rederictTo but still always loads homepage.

.app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'overview', loadChildren: './overview/overview.module#OverviewPageModule' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
/...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

.app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

.home.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
];
```

.overview.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OverviewPage
  }
];
```

.app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
/...
```

Comment: The code you show is correct. You must have some error in your @NgModules if you post those as well, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @benra I posted my NgModules

Comment: Ok, I think the one for your app-routing.module is important

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use OverviewModule instead of OverviewPageModule in your loadChild.

Comment: It does not work. I get an error that it cannot find OverviewModule

Answer (score 0):

I just called a navigation function in a route guard for this.

The goal was to route to a login page on app start, and prevent navigation to the other pages until authenticated (and vice versa - disable login route if already logged in).

It ended up looking something like this (the route guards are basically identical with opposite logic and a couple extra checks in the login guard):

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [TabsGuardService],
        resolve: {
            login: MidShiftLoginResolve
        },
        loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        canActivate: [LoginGuardService], // Routes back to '' if logged in already.
        loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule)
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**tabs.guard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TabsGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private login: LoginService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> |
            Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        const auth = this.login.isAuthenticated; // custom login service state
        if (!auth) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']).then(null);
        }
        return auth;
    }
}
```